Ubuntu 22.04 changed out of daylight savings time one week early
On an America/New_York time zone, with "Automatic Date & Time" enabled, Ubuntu 22.04 unexpectedly changed to EST from EDT this morning:
$ timedatectl
               Local time: Sun 2024-10-27 10:49:59 EST
           Universal time: Sun 2024-10-27 15:49:59 UTC
                 RTC time: Sun 2024-10-27 15:49:59
                Time zone: America/New_York (EST, -0500)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no

I am not seeing any other posts about this, but it's a problem for me. I've tried toggling the "Automatic Date & Time" setting a few times in the Settings app, but it changes back to EST. All the other locations in the map view have "-ST" suffixes also.
I can set the time manually but would rather let the OS handle this properly.
This is the result of apt policy tzdata:
tzdata:
  Installed: 2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Candidate: 2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
     2022a-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages


Please edit your question to show us the complete output of apt policy tzdata

You may be interested in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1531416/today-ubuntu-is-displaying-pst-instead-of-pdt (TLDR their tzdata file got corrupted; does sudo apt reinstall tzdata solve your problem too?)

@Wolfgang, thank you for the pointer. My machine exhibited all the same differences that user had. After reinstalling with sudo apt reinstall tzdata, running dpkg --verify tzdata showed no issues, but the timezone was not automatically fixed. I went back to the "set your timezone" interface, and after clicking the correct region, EST changed to EDT (correct!). It took about a minute for the UI to update accordingly, but it's fixed now!
