Today Ubuntu is displaying PST instead of PDT
What controls daylight savings vs standard time on GNU/Linux Ubuntu?
This morning I discovered that my Ubuntu laptop is showing time roughly one hour earlier than the rest of the Pacific Time regime.  I found plenty of advice online for how to change my timezone, but I haven't found a way to control daylight savings as a setting.
Screenshot shows difference between computer time and local time and various settings.  Is this strange?  I've never encountered this problem before.
Update: The cut-over from daylight savings to standard time happens at the end of this week (3 Nov).
Update2: uname -a
Linux ganymede 6.8.0-47-generic #47~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Oct  2 16:16:55 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Update3: output of apt policy tzdata
tzdata:
  Installed: 2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Candidate: 2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
     2022a-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages

Update4: Likely culprit: Europe cuts over to standard time a week earlier than the United States, so their time servers have already switched, which means that my machine is probably connected to an EU time server.  Hat-tip to @tomwsmf@mastodon.social for this insight.


Well, the culprit is seemingly not tzdata. You have the correct, latest version of that package.

@user535733 It seems that EU time servers switch from daylight savings to standard time a week earlier than U.S., which appears to be the problem.  How my computer in the Western United States happens to be connecting to EU time servers is an unanswered question, however.

NTP protocol that is used to synchronize time on the Internet always uses UTC and doesn't know about time zones - time zones are local to a particular computer. So it's unlikely that a time server is the reason (which is also confirmed by your answer).

With the help of a friend, we determined that the tzdata package on my Ubuntu 22.01 machine had become weirdly corrupt, such that my computer changed from PDT to PST on 27 Oct 2024 (EU) rather than 3 Nov 2024 (US).  UTC time was always correct.
The quick answer was to reinstall tzdata: apt reinstall tzdata, and now my computer is back on PDT.
We learned several things along the way, prior to the reinstall-

Running zdump /usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/America/Los_Angeles -v indicated the EU cutover dates-

...
/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/America/Los_Angeles  Sun Apr  7 09:59:59 2024 UT = Sun Apr  7 01:59:59 2024 PST isdst=0 gmtoff=-28800
/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/America/Los_Angeles  Sun Apr  7 10:00:00 2024 UT = Sun Apr  7 03:00:00 2024 PDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-25200
/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/America/Los_Angeles  Sun Oct 27 08:59:59 2024 UT = Sun Oct 27 01:59:59 2024 PDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-25200
/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/America/Los_Angeles  Sun Oct 27 09:00:00 2024 UT = Sun Oct 27 01:00:00 2024 PST isdst=0 gmtoff=-28800
...


dpkg --verify tzdata showed serious issues with the contents of /usr/share/zoneinfo (provided by tzdata)-

...
??5??????   /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Juneau
??5??????   /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/La_Paz
??5??????   /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Lima
??5??????   /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles
??5??????   /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Maceio
??5??????   /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Managua
??5??????   /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Manaus
...


Comparing the timestamp of the files under /usr/share/zoneinfo with a friend's Ubuntu 22.01, we found them to be different (14 Oct 2023 for me, 3 May 2024 for them)

We both had the exact same package info-


$ dpkg -s tzdata
Package: tzdata
Status: install ok installed
Priority: important
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 3900
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: 2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
Provides: tzdata-bookworm
Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0
Description: time zone and daylight-saving time data
 This package contains data required for the implementation of
 standard local time for many representative locations around the
 globe. It is updated periodically to reflect changes made by
 political bodies to time zone boundaries, UTC offsets, and
 daylight-saving rules.
Homepage: https://www.iana.org/time-zones
Original-Maintainer: GNU Libc Maintainers <debian-glibc@lists.debian.org>


We had different sha512 hashes for the America/Los_Angeles file.  Post-reinstall, mine now matches my friend's Ubuntu 22.01 machine, which did not exhibit the problem.

$ sha512sum /usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/America/Los_Angeles
# mine
e44291244b65ec5307284041f34545cb5ddbad13d1ad4e000341ece9318580048351ff3aef4050399a94dc95c55b7ce8ea28658b779ada326b980747dc7e5de7  /usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/America/Los_Angeles

# theirs
89f9698b4dac098182947ca09befcb93be5132c8a8e1ed4c3da7125e82ef376c47a544f26ffe9893210af587c37b4a483571ff47d5b599ad670d72f90fff0bfa  /usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/America/Los_Angeles



Post-reinstall, dpkg shows the same package version info-

$ dpkg -s tzdata
Package: tzdata
Status: install ok installed
Priority: required
Section: localization
Installed-Size: 3900
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: 2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
Provides: tzdata-bookworm
Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0
Description: time zone and daylight-saving time data
 This package contains data required for the implementation of
 standard local time for many representative locations around the
 globe. It is updated periodically to reflect changes made by
 political bodies to time zone boundaries, UTC offsets, and
 daylight-saving rules.
Homepage: https://www.iana.org/time-zones
Original-Maintainer: GNU Libc Maintainers <debian-glibc@lists.debian.org>


A zgrep/zless of apt logs shows that the tzdata package had been automatically updated in July 2024.. and that hadn't changed things...

Log started: 2024-07-05  17:29:35
(Reading database ... 5% ... 100% ...
...
Preparing to unpack .../tzdata_2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking tzdata (2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04) ...
Setting up tzdata (2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Current default time zone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
Local time is now:      Fri Jul  5 17:29:37 PDT 2024.
Universal Time is now:  Sat Jul  6 00:29:37 UTC 2024.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

To sum it up, we can see that tzdata's files had become corrupted -but were still usable EXCEPT for Daylight Savings Time ending a week early!  But we don't know why this happened.  It smells like a bug, but it's unclear what caused it.  We did find one other instance of early Daylight Savings-to-Standard time cutover, for a user in the EDT/EST timezone.
